# Why uses implicit_cast<size_t>(int) instead of static_cast<size_t>(int)?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-implicit-cast

I have read some code in muduo, an open source network library, and I found that the author use `implicit_cat<size_t>(int)` rather than `static_cast<size_t>(int)` in many place. The definition of  `implicit_cast` is as follows:

```
// Use implicit_cast as a safe version of static_cast or const_cast
// for upcasting in the type hierarchy (i.e. casting a pointer to Foo
// to a pointer to SuperclassOfFoo or casting a pointer to Foo to
// a const pointer to Foo).
// When you use implicit_cast, the compiler checks that the cast is safe.
// Such explicit implicit_casts are necessary in surprisingly many
// situations where C++ demands an exact type match instead of an
// argument type convertable to a target type.
//
// The From type can be inferred, so the preferred syntax for using
// implicit_cast is the same as for static_cast etc.:
//
//   implicit_cast<ToType>(expr)
//
// implicit_cast would have been part of the C++ standard library,
// but the proposal was submitted too late.  It will probably make
// its way into the language in the future.
template<typename To, typename From>
inline To implicit_cast(From const &f)
{
  return f;
}
```

I can understand what the comment means. Here is a example:

```
class Top{};
class MiddleA : public Top{};
class MiddleB : public Top{};
class Bottom : public MiddleA, public MiddleB{};
void func(MiddleA const& A){
    cout << "A" << endl;
}
void func(MiddleB const& B){
    cout << "B" << endl;
}
int main(){
    Top bot;
    func(implicit_cast<MiddleA const&>(bot));  //error
    func(implicit_cast<MiddleB const&>(bot)); //error
}
```

When it comes to upcasting in the type hierarchy, the `implicit_cast` can detect whether the cast from the tyep From to the type To is legitimate while the `static_cast` cannot. But why use `implicit_cast<size_t>(int)` instead of `static_cast<size_t>(int)` ?
There are two possible reasons I guess for this:

- `implicit_cast` is more meaningful than `static_cast`
- `size_t` is implementation-dependent, so `implicit_cast` is safer than `static_cast`

But I don't know which one is true. Maybe both of them are false.

Comment: I doubt vey much that this thing will make its way into the standard, at least, not with that name. Casts are never implicit. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. Conversions can be implicit or explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But why use `implicit_cast<size_t>(int)` instead of `static_cast<size_t>(int)`?

For the same reason as in the class case. In general, the reason is also the same as why C style casts are discouraged: Prefer using the cast which allows minimal set of casts that contains the cast that you want so that you don't accidentally perform a cast that you don't want.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I can't get your point. It would be better if you can give me an example .